# Method that prints to file

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I trying to figure out a way so I could write content from my methods 
to a file.
So I figured I need some sort of printMethod that let me print stuff to the file.

I've got a bunch of methods that print stuff to the console, but cant access all the varibles outside of the method. So need too find a way to print variables from different methods out
to a textfile.
Hope you understand.

Comment: The classic way is to call a method in your object that returns the string you need to print.  Perhaps you have some code fragments that illustrate your dilemma?

Comment: try https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+write+a+file+in+java and http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: So I should just declare new printWriters in every method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with the sort of logging you're getting to the console but you want it in a file then you could create a PrintStream with using a file name and use that instead of `System.out`.

```
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream("MyFile.txt");
    out.println("foo");
```

Comment: Printstream better than printWriter?

Comment: But if I have 5 methods that all print information to the console, and I want them to print to a file aswell. Should I just declare new printStreams in all the methods?